# C# Client-Server Video streaming

Tags: c#, video, streaming, video-streaming, client-server

Are there any c# libraries to facilitate the streaming of video in a client-server architecture? I would also be interested in finding some resources to learn more on the subject of video streaming on the .NET platform, and streaming in general.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to consume or produce the stream?

Comment: ultimately I would be writing both the client and server side of the system

Comment: Do you need to do it yourself, or can you rely on IIS to stream it for you?

Comment: I suppose iis would be an option. Would wcf services be useful at all in a situation like this?  I have very minimal video experience

Comment: I suppose you could use WCF.  Streaming from IIS, it looks like you just install [this](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/620/getting-started-with-iis-live-smooth-streaming/).  Streaming video with WCF would look something like [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gblock/archive/2010/11/24/streaming-over-http-with-wcf.aspx).  What do you hope to gain from using WCF?

Comment: Wcf was just the first thing tthat came to mind really . Thank you, I will check out the links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my previous attempts at this very problem I have always come to the conclusion (from other people's recommendations) that this book is the keystone piece to that problem - [http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Microsoft-DirectShow-Television-Pro-Developer/dp/0735618216](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735618216)

I had read before that it was out of print and only used copies were available at around $150 - but it looks like there are now new prints available which has dropped the price down to around $90 - but you still have to contend with it being a technology that Microsoft has deemed depracated (but they haven't replaced it with anything new yet) and of course if you look at the reviews on the book it certainly doesn't seem worth even $40 which would be my cap on something written almost a decade ago.

That being said - it has been about two years since I was attempting such a project so this information may be as deprecated as directx itself! ;)